# How to provide a multi word parameter to Vorpal.js

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, vorpal.js

Using this:

```
vorpal
.command("echo <somewords>")
.description("Outputs 'what ever you typed")
.action(function (args, callback) {
    this.log(args.somewords);
    callback();
});
```

I can enter: echo 'some text to echo' 
and that works as expected,  but echo "some other text"
just echo's "some

1. Is there a way to tell the option to include the rest of the line
2. A way to use both ' or " to encase a multi word paramter

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [variadic arguments](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/api-%7C-vorpal.command#variadic-arguments), by adding a `...` to the argument. This returns each word back in an array:

```
vorpal
.command("echo <somewords...>")
.description("Outputs 'what ever you typed")
.action(function (args, callback) {
    this.log(args.somewords.join(' '));
    callback();
});
```